# Issue in Sensor when vibration starts in android device

Tags: android, sensors

I am stuck with a major problem in an application.Now i give up seriously :(
Please guys help me to sort out this problem.Lets discuss the issue.

Actually I am using the **sensor** listener to detect the movement in the device.A **timer** starts for **2 minutes** and with in it if motion occur the timer reset itself.Now after 2 minutes if no motion detected then the alarm with **vibration** starts in a service and again in the mean time if motion occurs then the timer reset itself.It continues.. Now the problem arises that when there is no vibration and sound,the sensor works fine but when the 2 minutes over and the device goes in vibration mode the motion **detected automatically** and the timer **reset** itself.This is happening because the vibration and sound affect the sensor.Now  What i want that if the vibration will activate the sensor should not work until the device moves.

Below is my code:-

```
        private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private final float NOISE = (float)0.5;
    private float mLastX,mLastY,mLastZ;

    @Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    vib= (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(GuardMeService.this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

             @Override
         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        float x=event.values[0];
        float y=event.values[1];
        float z=event.values[2];


        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);

        if(deltaX>NOISE){
            compareX();
        }
        else if(deltaY>NOISE){
            compareX();
        }
        else if(deltaZ>NOISE){

            compareX();
        }

        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;

    }
}

private void compareX(){

    mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    vib.cancel();
    GuardMeActivity.timerView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    stopService(new                   Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmServiceForGuardMe.class));
    System.out.println("Movemenet>><><><><><><>><Occur");
```

}

Guys Please help me to sort out this problem.Thanks a lot in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Determine by how much "the vibration and sound affect the sensor", then ignore readings below that threshold.

Comment: If I give the NOISE value to 5.8 something then the vibration will not effect the sensor.But in that case a huge movement or shaking the device required .So I can't do that..Please suggest me some other option...Thanks !! :(

Comment: @DeepakSharma: Then stop using the vibration motor.

Comment: @DeepakSharma since you know when you activate the alarm you could either adjust the threshold during that time or even turn sensor evaluation off.

Comment: I can't do that..This is the client requirement.He wants sound and vibration both at the same time... Please try to help me .My application is not going to be delivered to client just because of this issue.. :'(

Comment: @DeepakSharma: Your client is welcome to move to some other universe where the laws of physics allow you to create a device that both moves and does not move at the same time. Either do what zapi suggests (ignore vibrations during the time the vibration motor is in use), or stop using the vibration motor entirely.

Comment: @Zapl I can't adjust the threshold as you can see my first comment as well as can't turn the sensor off because when the vibration activates then the motion in the device does not detected.:( Please Zapl suggest me some other option..My application is not going to be delivered to client just because of this issue.. :'( –

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there no way to fulfill the Client's requirement??

Comment: @DeepakSharma: Not in this universe. The best you will be able to do is only support "huge movement or shaking the device" while you are using the vibration motor. Your client will need to decide what is more important: detecting less movement (in which case, you need to ignore or stop using the vibration motor) or the vibrations (in which case, you will need to apply a higher NOISE value when the vibration motor is in use by you). Also note that you have no way of knowing if *some other app* uses the vibration motor.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay I got your point. Now i will try to make understand the things to my client which you have discussed me.. Thanks a lot dude !! :)

Comment: @DeepakSharma Vibration and sound generate a magnetic field which affects the magnetic field sensor. Vibration also actually moves the device and affects the other sensors. You could have a look at the raw sensor values for each sensor and see if there is a better sensor to use (I doubt it - ACCELEROMETER should be one of the least affected). The next thing you could do - which goes way beyond my knowledge - is to apply e.g. bandpass filtering if the fake motion has a certain frequency or look into advanced [sensor fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion#Sensor_fusion_algorithms)

Comment: @Zapl Can you please provide me a sample code which fulfills my requirement??

Comment: @DeepakSharma No. I don't have such code. As CommonsWare said, talk to your client if there is a simple solution to your problem or do some research on those topics. [How Can I Remove Vibration Noise From My Accelerometer?](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/how-can-i-remove-vibration-noise-from-my-accelerometer) sounds like a good start and [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=kalman+vibration+filter) is always helpful to find scientific research papers that discuss those techniques.

Comment: Hello Zapl and Commons Ware, I talked to the client and tried to understand the things which are not possible but he refused to do so.Now I have to implement the vibration functionality with the proper sensor works.Please try to help me..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer .. I have to disable the vibration motor in the device.